# How to deal with arbitrary size for Laplacian Pyramid?

Tags: math, image-processing, graphics, gaussian, imaging

Recently I had much fun with the Laplacian Pyramid algorithm (http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/pyramid83.pdf). But one big problem is that the original paper is limited to 2^m+1*2^n+1 images. My question is: What is the best way to deal with arbitrary w*h instead? I can think of a couple of options:

- Up sample the input to the next 2^m+1,2^n+1 up front
- Pad even lines. How exactly? Wouldn't it shift the signal?
- Shift even lines by half a sample? Wouldn't it loose half a sample?

Does anybody have experience with this?  What is the most practical and efficient approach? Also any pointers to papers dealing with this would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to create an image with a width and height equal to the next 2^m+1,2^n+1, but instead of up-sampling the image to fill the expanded dimensions, just place it in the top-left corner and fill the empty space to the right and below with a constant value (the average value for the image is a good choice for this). Then encode in the normal way, storing the original image dimensions along with the pyramid. When decoding, decode and then crop to the original size.

This won't introduce any visual artifacts or degradation because you aren't stretching or offsetting the image in any way.

Because the empty space to the right and below the original image is a constant value, the high-pass bands at each level in the image pyramid will be all zero in this area. So if you are using a compression scheme like run length encoding to store each level this will be automatically taken care off and these areas will be compressed to almost nothing. If not then you can simply store the top-left (potentially non-zero) area of each level and then fill out the rest with zeros when decoding.

You could find the min and max x and y bounding rectangle of the non-zero values for each level and store this along with the level, cropped to include only non-zero values. The decoder could also be optimized so that areas of the image that are going to be cropped away are not actually decoded in the first place, by only processing the top-left of each level.

Here's an illustration of the technique:

[image]

Instead of just filling the lower-right area with a flat color, you could fill it with horizontally and vertically mirrored copies of the image to the right and below, and a copy mirrored in both directions to the bottom-right, like this:

[image]

This will avoid the discontinuities of the first technique, although there will be a discontinuity in dx (e.g. if the value was gradually increasing from left to right it will suddenly be decreasing). Choosing a mirror that keeps dx constant and ddx zero will avoid this second-order discontinuity by linearly extrapolating the values.

Another technique, which is similar to what some JPEG encoders do to pad out an image to a whole number of MCU blocks, is to take the last pixel value of each row and repeat it, and likewise for columns, with the bottom-right-most pixel of the image used to fill the bottom-right area:

[image]

This last technique could easily be modified to extrapolate the gradient of values or even the gradient of gradients instead of just repeating the same value for the remainder of the row or column.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful reply. I am actually not that interested in compression - it was just the easiest free paper on the algorithm. Blending is the real application! One thing that worries me with padding is that it creates a rather harsh discontinuity at every frequency higher than the lowest? The paper chooses a mirror that keeps dx constant and ddx zero as is at the edges. For good reason? As I see it the only requirement is that the sum property will hold. Intuitively it is possible when rounding the size up? But how to keep it centered?

Comment: Mirroring or smearing instead of filling with a flat color will avoid a discontinuity (see updated answer). I couldn't find where in the paper it mentions choosing a mirror, so I'm not sure how to answer all of your questions, but I would guess that avoiding such a discontinuity is the reason. The one concern I would have is that such an extrapolation could produce values outside the valid range e.g. negative values. Basically you are just trying to synthesize plausible pixel values off the edge of the image, the simplest technique that avoids visible artifacts is probably the best.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it is very thorough! Thanks! I also found this paper from the same authors that talks explicitly about boundary conditions at 2.4: http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/spline83.pdf. They recommend the mirroring you also suggest. I am still fighting a bit with how to properly handle blending between two differently sized or offset images. Again thanks for the answer it helped me think about the problem a lot.

Comment: To expand: I am convinced now that proper padding is the way to go instead of making the pyramid work on arbitrary sizes.